# Progression in an activity within Omnistudio

Tags: salesforce

I'm having trouble continuing activity within OmniStudio Salesforce because I don't know much about the tool, could you help me? I have to add a button with a call to an external API that validates whether the email typed is a temporary email or not (disposable tag) and display text with a message
conditional on whether the email is valid or not according to the response from the service. Would you be able to help me? I even added the button, but I don't know how to make this API call and where to configure it

[I can't get past this part. I created some things requested, however, I can't progress.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sUek.png)